# why does changing the `background-color` of a button change other styles too?

Tags: css

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwKOaz

Changing only the `background-color` significantly changes the style on a button element, specifically the `border` style.

[image: background change]

This happens on chrome, safari, and firefox on a Mac. Why does this happen? How can I safely change its background color?

Comment: Not seeing this behavior on Windows 7, Chrome... buttons look identical except for the background color, as you'd expect. Have you tried using `background` in place of `background-color`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that.

Comment: similar result on ubuntu

Comment: NOTE: changing just `margin` on button doesn't have this effect apparently. `padding` however does trigger change in design.

Answer (score 11):

Browser vendors apply custom styling to UI elements like buttons and input fields. Altering one of these overwritten attributes results in disabling all of the other vendor styles on that element as well. If you want to change one attribute, you have to alter the others as well, I'm afraid.

Unfortunately I can't tell you why they do this - probably there is might be some spec behind, but I cannot find any evidence for that.

Answer (score 4):

When all the styles are untouched, the browser uses the host OS's given API to render the given control. This will make the control look native to the platform, but if you apply any style to that control/element, the browser cannot guarantee that the given style can be applied in the given platform, so it defaults back to a simplified, fully css solution.

Also note, that styling control elements, though works, not covered by stable standards yet.

For example, the NSButton (native control behind the button in OS X) doesn't have an option to set the background color, so the browser faces an impossible task. On Windows, you can change the background color, this is why people report not seeing your issue on Windows.

Comment: Happens on windows as well.

Comment: @Christoph The behaviour is browser, OS version and also OS theme dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes CSS styles are inherited. However, you are applying styles to your body which is everything in HTML. Personally I don't apply anything to body other than maybe reset or normalize CSS. That said, you can use CSS selector operators and\or id/classes to minimize:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Example:

html

btw don't write html like this just easier to read

```
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
          <button class="all-btns red">
              Cancel
          </button>

          <button class="all-btns green">
               Save
          </button>
    </div>
</body>
```

css

```
.div.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: #efefef;
}

.all-btns {
    border: solid 1px #000; 
    width: 50px;
    line-height: 48px;
    height 35px;
    color: #fff;
}

.btn.red {
    color: #fff;
    background: red;
}
.btn.green {
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: huh? How is that related to the question?