# Bug? Chrome on Mac ignores submit button font-size

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome

Sometimes you think you're going insane. This one of those times.
While working I had an issue that I couldn't change the font-size of a submit button. Then after going insane I boiled it down to this simple example:

https://jsfiddle.net/zf9sq2gx/

```
font-size: 100px;
```

I am sure this looks perfectly fine on your machine, but it does not on mine.
See:
[image]

I am working on a Mac here and this result is from Chrome.
 - Firefox works as expected
 - Other pages I made or visit online do work, however this basic example and the page I am working on right now, they exhibit this behavior.

It does not matter which number or unit of font size. Other values like padding are also ignored. WIDTH however is NOT ignored.
When changing the font-size in the chrome dev tools, the button flickers from its current font-size to a smaller one, but instantly jumps back. Even tho it should at least flicker to a big one in this case.
What if we change it to a different tag altogether? Now it works.
What if we just change the type from submit to text? It behaves as expected again.
What if we remove even the other tags like body and form and everything? Doesn't matter.

[image]
[image]

Updating meme. No change.

**How could this possibly be a thing?**
Not to mention that other pages may work with submit buttons. But I made this example in jsfiddle as simple as possible to go back to bare minimum, even using inline CSS (because !important did nothing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

It will cancel default chrome styles for a button.

Comment: That does do the trick. I forgot to try this one.
Of course it doesn't really explain why this is happening, why only on Mac, why only on some pages.

Comment: There are default user agent styles:    
  
`input[type="button" i], input[type="submit" i], input[type="reset" i] {
    -webkit-appearance: push-button;
    user-select: none;
    white-space: pre;
}` . 

You can even change  `push-button` to `button` and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Petruk Dmitry's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7663294/petruk-dmitry) solution, you can solve this by setting `-webkit-appearance: none`, or by overwriting one of the vendor styles, if you don't want to add browser specific CSS. Appearantly, overwriting any of the vendor styles (see below for a list of tested styles) will remove the button styling completely. I've never had this problem before since I normally change the background and border when styling a button.

Examples:

```html
<input type="submit" style="font-size: 60px;"><br />
<input type="submit" style="font-size: 60px; -webkit-appearance: none;" value="Webkit appearance"><br />
<input type="submit" style="font-size: 60px; background: blue;" value="background"><br />
<input type="submit" style="font-size: 60px; border: 1px solid green;" value="border">
```

EDIT: (some) More information on this behaviour can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26983505/why-does-changing-the-background-color-of-a-button-change-other-styles-too), though it seems as if this "feature" isn't very well documented. For more reading on the subject however, you can check [this page](https://css-tricks.com/overriding-default-button-styles/).

Comment: Right before this I worked on a form where the button was blue, and I did not have this problem. This would explain it. Pretty crazy.